# What is wrong with my makefile for C?

Tags: c, makefile

I am currently learning C. I tried to make a makefile, but for some reason, it doesn't work. When I type "make" into the console, the following warnings are printed into the console:

```
makefile.c:1:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
  [-Wimplicit-int]
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
^~~~~~
makefile.c:1:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Wall'
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
    ^
makefile.c:1:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'g'
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
          ^
makefile.c:4:13: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
rm -f ex1
```

Here is the makefile's code:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

clean:
   rm -f ex1
```

The code is expected to compile the file ex1.c . Why doesn't my makefile work?

Comment: `makefile.c`.....well, that's not the way....

Comment: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html You should check here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `make` it tries to figure out what you want it to do.

By default it looks for a file called `Makefile` or `makefile` (and for GNU Make, it first looks for `GNUMakefile`). If it finds such a file, it assumes it is a makefile and reads it.

It seems that here `make` finds something that looks *a bit like* a makefile, but then guesses what to do with it. In your case it finds your file `makefile.c` which it assumes is a source file containing C code, so it uses its built-in rules for processing C source files and tries to compile it with the C compiler. That fails, because your makefile is not a C program! (You lied by naming it `makefile.c`)

You can either tell `make` to read that file explicitly (even though it has an unconventional name) by running `make -f makefile.c`, or you can just give it a sensible name (either `Makefile` or `makefile`) so that it gets found automatically when you run `make`.

When `make` processes a makefile the first target it finds is the default target. In your makefile the first target is `clean` so when make runs it will run the rules for the `clean` target. If you want it to run a different target then either put another target first in the makefile, or specify a target explicitly, e.g. `make ex1` (which will cause `make` to see the file `ex1.c` and use its built-in rules for compiling a C source file into an executable).

Answer (score 6):

`Makefiles` are instruction to `make`, and they are not programs in the same sense as a c-program.  From the error messages it looks like you have named your `Makefile` as a c-source code file, so

1. Rename your make file to `Makefile`

   ```
   mv makefile.c Makefile
   ```

Your `makefile` does not specify what to make -- it only has a `clean` tag, but not to worry, if your source code is in a single file then `make` can figure it out, just;

2. Specify what you want to make

   ```
   $ make ex1
   ```

   or alternatively have an entry in your Makefile to do the same, like

   ```
   CFLAGS=-Wall -g

   ex1: ex1.c   # This will tell make that ex1 is compiled from ex1.c

   clean:
       rm -f ex1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A Makefile is not a C file.

You shall rename it from makefile.c to Makefile (mv ./makefile.c ./Makefile)

After on, in your CFLAGS, use -W -ansi -Werror and don't forget to remove the -g when your done, otherwise, your program will be slower on execution.

And then, as it's not a C file, don't try to compile it with gcc

Just type

```
make
```

or any other rule you got preceded by make, as

```
make re; make clean
```

if you wanna compile the whole thing, then clean trash files (*.o and auto-saves depending on your rules aswell).

Comment: _"don't forget to remove the -g when your done, otherwise, your program will be slower on execution."_ Not true. Debug info has no runtime cost, it only makes the executable take more disk space.

Comment: Since the -g is compiled with the code, I thought debug infos were read at the same time as the program is, my bad. But anyway, it does not change much,  he gotta get it out when he's done.

Comment: Why? Unless you are short on disk space (or want to make it intentionally difficult to debug the program) there is no reason not to leave `-g` there. Lots of people leave debug info in production builds.

Comment: Also as an FYI, when you don't need the debug symbols anymore, you can use `strip` to remove them

Comment: @JonathanWakely Because when selling your program to a customer, this is non-professional. That's what my school taught me

Comment: Why not compile with debug info and distribute a stripped copy, keeping an unstripped copy for yourself so you can debug coredumps from the customer? What if your customer wants to be able to debug the program themselves? Who says the OP has customers anyway? I think your school gave you bad advice, and telling a beginner to do something that makes debugging harder seems counter-productive.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That was just a tip I gave him. I know he surely got no customer by now, but later ? And as I said, he shall remove them when he's done. Not when debugging is not over yet.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Assuming the code behavior is identical in the larger version, a larger code segment definitely has a cost that is equal *or greater*. That cost can result in a slower execution.

Comment: @this, but debug info is not in the code segment, so it doesn't make it larger.

Answer (score -1):

Makefile doesn't have extension. Change makefile.c to makefile then try.
Suppose you want create makefile for file1.c & file2.c, here file1.c is depend on file2.c create makefile as given below

```
makefile: file1.c file2.c  
gcc -o makefile file1.c file2.c
```

And you can just compile using command

```
make makefile
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem by doing the following:

See your all characters in your file, specially in "clean", does not change color even though you saved.

I don't think you saved correctly.

Open `gedit` and paste your code, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save it and then name it to `Makefile`, not `Makefile.c`. Makefile is makefile type.

When you save, check file `Makefile` by clicking the file property. If you see Type: maketype is Ok or see all the characters in your file, the "clean" will change color from grey to another color.

Finally, in `terminal`, write `make clean`, not `make Makefile`. It will run like it does in the "learnCthehardcode" course.